# Raphael drag clone onDragOver

Tags: raphael, clone, drag

Currently I drag a clone of a draggable Raphael element by using `element.clone()` in the `dragStart` function and moving the clone in the `dragMove` function (removing it in the `dragStop` function).

This raises an issue with the `onDragOver` function for the draggable element since most of the time the clone throws the corresponding event instead of the targeted one.

Some code:

```
dragStart = function() {
    var s = this, c = s.clone();
    s.data('clone', c);
    c.ox = c.attr('cx'); 
    c.oy = c.attr('cy');
};
dragMove = function(dx, dy) {
    var s = this, c = s.data('clone');
    c.attr({cx:c.ox+dx, cy:c.oy+dy});
};
dragStop = function() {
    this.data('clone').remove();
};
onDragOver = function(el) {
    console.log(el); // displays most of the time the clone  
};
elementToDrag.drag(dragMove, dragStart, dragStop);
elementToDrag.onDragOver(onDragOver);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sleeping a night over it I changed the approach of the clone itself by dragging the original and set a clone at its position. Thus I keep the original position and the `onDragOver` function shows the correct target element.

```
dragStart = function() {
    var s = this, c = s.clone(); // clone stays at the original position
    s.data('clone', c);
    s.ox = s.attr('cx');
    s.oy = s.attr('cy');
};
dragMove = function(dx, dy) {
    var s = this;
    s.attr({cx:s.ox+dx, cy:s.oy+dy}); // but now the original is being dragged
};
dragStop = function() {
    var c = this.data('clone');
    this.attr({cx: c.attr('cx'), cy: c.attr('cy')}); // put original at the position of the clone
    this.data('clone').remove(); // and remove the clone
};
onDragOver = function(el) {
    console.log(el); // now only the targeted element is shown
};
elementToDrag.drag(dragMove, dragStart, dragStop);
elementToDrag.onDragOver(onDragOver);
```